# A* search on 4x4 sliding tile puzzle scales poorly

Tags: c, time-limit-exceeded, pthreads, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am trying to improve the time complexity of my A* search algorithm and I have tried approaching this from every which way I believe is possible. I believe I may be doing something fundamentally wrong here and would appreciate a second look.

I start with a 4x4 board of values 0-15 that can be shuffled to achieve this order (**where `0` represents a blank spot**)

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15  0
```

**The catch:** when running this program on a board with a minor change like:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10  0 11
13 14 15 12
```

The program executes **fine**

But in more complex cases, say 15 moves are made from original board instead of just 2, the program takes an absurd amount of time to complete when I am aiming for 1-2 min execution time.

```
 6  2  3  7
10 12  4 11
 1 13  0  9
 5 14 15  8
```

This case above takes an absurd amount of time.

The program is called in this fashion:

```
./a.out -s 6 2 3 7 10 12 4 11 1 13 0 9 5 14 15 8
```

where `-m` flag signals multithreading and `-s` signals single thread.

Included below is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 4
#define NxN (N*N)
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct node {
    int tiles[N][N];
    int f, g, h;
    short zero_row, zero_column; /* location (row and colum) of blank tile 0 */
    struct node *next;
    struct node *parent; /* used to trace back the solution */
};

// globals
int goal_rows[NxN];
int goal_columns[NxN];
struct node *start,*goal;
struct node *open = NULL, *closed = NULL;
struct node *succ_nodes[4];
pthread_barrier_t bar, barrier_before_filtering, barrier_after_filtering;
int finish=0, multithread=0;

// print board
void print_a_node(struct node *pnode) {
    int i,j;
    if (pnode != NULL) {
        for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<N;j++)
                printf("%2d ", pnode->tiles[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node *initialize(int argc, char **argv){
    int i,j,k,index, tile;
    struct node *pnode;

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    index = 1;
    for (j=0;j<N;j++) {
        for (k=0;k<N;k++) {
            tile=atoi(argv[index++]);
            pnode->tiles[j][k]=tile;
            if(tile==0) {
                pnode->zero_row=j;
                pnode->zero_column=k;
            }
        }
    }
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    pnode->parent=NULL;
    start=pnode;
    printf("initial state\n");
    print_a_node(start);

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    goal_rows[0]=3;
    goal_columns[0]=3;

    for(index=1; index<NxN; index++){
        j=(index-1)/N;
        k=(index-1)%N;
        goal_rows[index]=j;
        goal_columns[index]=k;
        pnode->tiles[j][k]=index;
    }
    pnode->tiles[N-1][N-1]=0;         /* empty tile=0 */
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    goal=pnode;
    printf("goal state\n");
    print_a_node(goal);

    return start;
}

/* merge unrepeated nodes into open list after filtering */
void merge_to_open() {

    struct node *temp;
    struct node *curr;
    struct node *the_succ_node;

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        curr = open;
        temp = open;
        if (succ_nodes[i] != NULL) {

            the_succ_node=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            for(int k=0;k<N;k++){
                for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
                    the_succ_node->tiles[k][j]=succ_nodes[i]->tiles[k][j];
                }
            }
            // copy data
            the_succ_node->zero_row = succ_nodes[i]->zero_row;
            the_succ_node->zero_column = succ_nodes[i]->zero_column;
            the_succ_node->parent = succ_nodes[i]->parent;
            the_succ_node->f = succ_nodes[i]->f;
            the_succ_node->g = succ_nodes[i]->g;
            the_succ_node->h = succ_nodes[i]->h;

            // insert at beginning if smallest
            if (curr == NULL) {
                open = the_succ_node;
            } else if (the_succ_node->f <= curr->f) {

                if (the_succ_node->h <= curr->h) {
                    the_succ_node->next = curr;
                    open = the_succ_node;
                } else {
                    while (1) {
                        temp = curr;
                        curr = curr->next;
                        if (curr == NULL) {
                            // insert at end of list
                            temp->next = the_succ_node;
                            the_succ_node->next = NULL;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (the_succ_node->h <= curr->h) {
                            the_succ_node->next = curr;
                            temp->next = the_succ_node;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else { // if not smallest
                while (1) {
                    temp = curr;
                    curr = curr->next;
                    if (curr == NULL) {
                        // insert at end of list
                        temp->next = the_succ_node;
                        the_succ_node->next = NULL;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (the_succ_node->f <= curr->f) {
                        the_succ_node->next = curr;
                        temp->next = the_succ_node;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*swap two tiles in a node*/
void swap(int row1,int column1,int row2,int column2, struct node * pnode){
    int tmp;
    tmp = pnode->tiles[row1][column1];
    pnode->tiles[row1][column1] = pnode->tiles[row2][column2];
    pnode->tiles[row2][column2] = tmp;
}

int manhattan(struct node * pnode) {
    int sum = 0;
    int ourValue = 0;
    int fbool = 0;
    // for each point, finding distance to
    // rest of the point
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            // grab our value
            ourValue = pnode->tiles[i][j];
            fbool = 0;
            for (int m = 0; m < N; m++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {

                    // found match
                    if (ourValue == goal->tiles[m][n]) {
                        sum += (abs(i - m) + abs(j - n));
                        fbool = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fbool) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

/*update the f,g,h function values for a node */
void update_fgh(struct node *pnode){
    // call manhattan distance for h
    pnode->h = manhattan(pnode);
    // check height of list for g
    pnode->g = pnode->parent->g+1;
    // add both for f
    pnode->f = pnode->g + pnode->h;
}

struct node *move(struct node *pnode, int xMove, int yMove) {

    struct node *newp;
    int i,j,h,xSpot,ySpot;

    xSpot = pnode->zero_row;
    ySpot = pnode->zero_column;
    // malloc
    newp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    // copy from orig
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            newp->tiles[i][j]=pnode->tiles[i][j];
        }
    }
    newp->next = NULL;
    newp->parent = pnode; // do we need to trace back here?
    newp->zero_row = xSpot+xMove;
    newp->zero_column = ySpot+yMove;
    swap(xSpot, ySpot, xSpot + xMove, ySpot + yMove, newp);;
    newp->h=0;
    newp->g=0;
    newp->f=0;
    return newp;
}

/* expand a node, get its children nodes, and organize the children nodes using
 * array succ_nodes.
 */
void expand(struct node *selected) {
    // set new nodes parents to selected
    int i, j;
    struct node *temp;
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++) {
        succ_nodes[k]=NULL;
    }
    i = selected->zero_row;
    j = selected->zero_column;

    if((i+1) < N){      /* DOWN */
        succ_nodes[0] = move(selected, 1, 0);
        update_fgh(succ_nodes[0]);
    }
    if((j+1) < N){      /* RIGHT */
        succ_nodes[1] = move(selected, 0, 1);
        update_fgh(succ_nodes[1]);
    }
    if((i-1) >=0){      /* UP */
        succ_nodes[2] = move(selected, -1, 0);
        update_fgh(succ_nodes[2]);
    }
    if((j-1) >=0){      /* LEFT */
        succ_nodes[3] = move(selected, 0, -1);
        update_fgh(succ_nodes[3]);
    }
}

// checks if nodes are same
int nodes_same(struct node *a,struct node *b) {
    int flg=FALSE;
    if (memcmp(a->tiles, b->tiles, sizeof(int)*NxN) == 0) {
        flg=TRUE;
    }
    return flg;
}

/* Filtering. Some nodes in succ_nodes may already be included in either open
 * or closed list. Remove them. It is important to reduce execution time.
 * This function checks the (i)th node in succ_nodes array. You must call this
 & function in a loop to check all the nodes in succ_nodes.
 */
void filter(int i, struct node *pnode_list) {

    struct node *temp;
    temp = pnode_list;

    if (succ_nodes[i] != NULL) {
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (nodes_same(succ_nodes[i], temp)) {
                if (succ_nodes[i]->f >= temp->f) {
                    succ_nodes[i] = NULL;
                    break;
                }
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void *filter_threads(void *id){
    int *myid = (int *)id;
    int found = 0;
    //printf("thread %d\n",*myid);
    while(1){
        // sync w main
        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier_before_filtering);
        //... /* check the found flag, and exit when found is set */
        if (finish) { break; }
        // filter
        filter(*myid, open);
        filter(*myid, closed);
        //... /* barrier sync */
        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier_after_filtering);
    }
}

void printnodes() {

    struct node *temp;
    temp = open;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("\nfor below open->f = %d, open->g = %d, open->h = %d\n", temp->f, temp->g, temp->h);
        print_a_node(temp);
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int iter, cnt, errno;
    struct node *copen, *cp, *solution_path;
    pthread_t thread[N-1];
    int ret, i, pathlen=0, index[N-1];
    solution_path=NULL;
    multithread = (strcmp(argv[1], "-m") == 0) ? 1 : 0; /* set multithread flag based on argv[1] */
    start=initialize(argc-1,argv+1);    /* init initial and goal states */
    open=start;

    // add catch for not -s or -m
    // add catch for argc != 17

    if(multithread){
        //printf("Multithread enabled\n");
        pthread_barrier_init(&bar, NULL, 4);
        pthread_barrier_init(&barrier_before_filtering, NULL, 4);
        pthread_barrier_init(&barrier_after_filtering, NULL, 4);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            index[i] = i+1;
            ret = pthread_create(thread+i, NULL, filter_threads, &(index[i]));
            if (ret != 0) {
                errno = ret; perror("pthread_create"); return -1;
            }

        }
    }
    iter=0;
    while (open!=NULL) {    /* Termination cond with a solution is tested in expand. */
        //printf("\nentered main while EXPAND iter = %d\n", iter);
        copen=open;
        open=open->next;  /* get the first node from open to expand */

        if(nodes_same(copen,goal)){
            if(multithread){
                finish=1;
                pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier_before_filtering);
                for (i=0; i < N-1; i++) {
                    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
                }
                pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier_before_filtering);
                pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier_after_filtering);
            }
            do{ /* trace back and add the nodes on the path to a list */
                copen->next=solution_path; // to maintain copen list
                solution_path=copen;
                copen=copen->parent;
                pathlen++;
            } while(copen!=NULL);
            printf("Path (length=%d):\n\n", pathlen);
            copen=solution_path;
            cp = copen; /* print out the nodes on the list */
            while (cp != NULL) {
                print_a_node(cp);
                cp = cp->next;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        // expand successive nodes into succ_nodes
        expand(copen);
        if(multithread){
            //... /* barrier sync */
            pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier_before_filtering);
            filter(0,open);
            filter(0,closed);
            //... /* barrier sync */
            pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier_after_filtering);
        }
        else{
            for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                filter(i,open);
                filter(i,closed);
            }
        }

        merge_to_open(); /* New open list */

        /* New closed */
        copen->next=closed;
        closed=copen;
        //merge_to_closed(copen);

        /* print out something so that you know your
         * program is still making progress
         */
        iter++;
        if(iter %1000 == 0) {
            printf("iter %d\n", iter);
        }

    }

    printf("\n\nNo solution found!!\n");
    return 0;
} /* end of main */
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged as [tag:c++]? Is there any reason you need this code to be bilingual, when you don't appear to be using any C++-specific features?

Comment: What does the program do? What is the expected output?

Comment: @200_success didn't know if the C tag was a well-monitored tag on its own, I apologize

Comment: If you consider your question adequately answered, you should consider selecting an answer for the question.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing the same mistake that everyone who posts that their A* is slow is doing.

You're using the wrong data structure for your open and closed structure. The closed should be a set, usually you choose a hashtable based one but a tree based one will do too. And the open set needs to be a priority queue which you typically implement using a heap.

Please search around on this site for other A* questions that will show your examples.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I really thought closed should be sorted in some fashion.

Comment: Closed is used to determine if you can avoid expanding a node, thus you only need to determine if the node is in the closed set. Hence hash table is preferred as your don't need ordering.